# how to port c/c++ applications to legacy linux kernel versions

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, glibc

Ok, this is just a bit of a fun exercise, but it can't be too hard compiling programmes for some older linux systems, or can it?

I have access to a couple of ancient systems all running linux and maybe it'd be interesting to see how they perform under load. Say as an example we want to do some linear algebra using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) which is a nice header-only library. Any chance to compile it on the target system?

```
user@ancient:~ $ uname -a
Linux local 2.2.16 #5 Sat Jul 8 20:36:25 MEST 2000 i586 unknown
user@ancient:~ $ gcc --version
egcs-2.91.66
```

Maybe not... So let's compile it on a current system. Below are my attempts, mainly failed ones. Any more ideas very welcome.

1. Compile with `-m32 -march=i386`

   ```
   user@ancient:~ $ ./a.out
   BUG IN DYNAMIC LINKER ld.so: dynamic-link.h: 53: elf_get_dynamic_info: Assertion `! "bad dynamic tag"' failed!
   ```
2. Compile with `-m32 -march=i386 -static`: Runs on all fairly recent kernel versions but fails if they are slightly older with the well known error message

   ```
   user@ancient:~ $ ./a.out
   FATAL: kernel too old
   Segmentation fault
   ```

   This is a `glibc` error which has a minimum kernel version it supports, e.g. kernel 2.6.4 on my system:

   ```
   $ file a.out
   a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV),
   statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, not stripped
   ```
3. Compile `glibc` myself with support for the oldest kernel possible. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004241/) describes it in more detail but essentially it goes like this

   ```
   wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.14.tar.bz2
   tar -xjf glibc-2.14.tar.bz2
   cd glibc-2.14
   mkdir build; cd build
   ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/glibc_32  \
                --enable-kernel=2.0.0 \
                --with-cpu=i486 --host=i486-linux-gnu \
                CC="gcc -m32 -march=i486"  CXX="g++ -m32 -march=i486"
   make -j 4
   make intall
   ```

   Not sure if the `--with-cpu` and `--host` options do anything, most important is to force the use of compiler flags `-m32 -march=i486` for 32-bit builds (unfortunately `-march=i386` bails out with errors after a while) and `--enable-kernel=2.0.0` to make the library compatible with older kernels. Incidentially, during `configure` I got the warning

   ```
   WARNING: minimum kernel version reset to 2.0.10
   ```

   which is still acceptable, I suppose. For a list of things which change with different kernels see `./sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/kernel-features.h`.

   Ok, so let's link against the newly compiled `glibc` library, slightly messy but here it goes:

   ```
   $ export LIBC_PATH=/usr/local/glibc_32
   $ export LIBC_FLAGS=-nostdlib -L${LIBC_PATH} \
                       ${LIBC_PATH}/crt1.o ${LIBC_PATH}/crti.o \
                       -lm -lc -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lstdc++ -lc \
                       ${LIBC_PATH}/crtn.o

   $ g++ -m32 -static prog.o ${LIBC_FLAGS} -o prog
   ```

   Since we're doing a static compile the [link order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/) is important and may well require some trial and error, but basically we learn from what options `gcc` gives to the linker:

   ```
   $ g++ -m32 -static -Wl,-v file.o
   ```

   Note, `crtbeginT.o` and `crtend.o` are also linked against which I didn't need for my programmes so I left them out. The output also includes a line like `--start-group -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc --end-group` which indicates inter-dependence between the libraries, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651869/). I just mentioned `-lc` twice in the `gcc` command line which also solves inter-dependence.

   Right, the hard work has paid off and now I get

   ```
   $ file ./prog
   ./prog: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV),
   statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.0.10, not stripped
   ```

   Brilliant I thought, now try it on the old system:

   ```
   user@ancient:~ $ ./prog
   set_thread_area failed when setting up thread-local storage
   Segmentation fault
   ```

   This, again, is a `glibc` error message from `./nptl/sysdeps/i386/tls.h`. I fail to understand the details and give up.
4. Compile on the new system `g++ -c -m32 -march=i386` and link on the old. Wow, that actually works for C and simple C++ programmes (not using C++ objects), at least for the few I've tested. This is not too surprising as all I need from `libc` is `printf` (and maybe some maths) of which the interface hasn't changed but the interface to `libstdc++` is very different now.
5. Setup a virtual box with an old linux system and gcc version 2.95. Then compile gcc version 4.x.x ... sorry, but too lazy for that right now ...
6. ???

Comment: Compile? A header-only template library?

Comment: Compile a test programme which uses this template library. This is just an example of some code which wouldn't compile on the target machine due to the outdated gcc version.

Comment: Ah, alright. Sorry, just misunderstood.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid STT_GNU_IFUNC symbols in your binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842194/how-to-avoid-stt-gnu-ifunc-symbols-in-your-binary)

Comment: Related in general but not a duplicate, I'd say. There are more related questions, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941332/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079717/). The contribution here is to actually having recompiled `glibc` to support kernels from 2.0.10 but then still getting an error `set_thread_area failed when setting up thread-local storage` when run on a 2.2.x kernel.

Answer (score 9):

Have found the reason for the error message:

```
user@ancient $ ./prog
set_thread_area failed when setting up thread-local storage
Segmentation fault
```

It's because `glibc` makes a system call to a function which is only available since kernel 2.4.20. In a way it can be seen as a bug of `glibc` as it wrongly claims to be compatible with kernel 2.0.10 when it requires at least kernel 2.4.20.

The details:

```
./glibc-2.14/nptl/sysdeps/i386/tls.h
[...]
     /* Install the TLS.  */                                                  \
     asm volatile (TLS_LOAD_EBX                                               \
                   "int $0x80\n\t"                                            \
                   TLS_LOAD_EBX                                               \
                   : "=a" (_result), "=m" (_segdescr.desc.entry_number)       \
                   : "0" (__NR_set_thread_area),                              \
                     TLS_EBX_ARG (&_segdescr.desc), "m" (_segdescr.desc));    \
[...]
     _result == 0 ? NULL                                                      \
     : "set_thread_area failed when setting up thread-local storage\n"; })
[...]
```

The main thing here is, it calls the assembly function `int 0x80` which is a system call to the linux kernel which decides what to do based on the value of `eax`, which is set to
`__NR_set_thread_area` in this case and is defined in

```
$ grep __NR_set_thread_area /usr/src/linux-2.4.20/include/asm-i386/unistd.h
#define __NR_set_thread_area    243
```

but not in any earlier kernel versions.

So the good news is that point "3. Compiling glibc with `--enable-kernel=2.0.0`" will probably produce executables which run on all linux kernels >= 2.4.20.

The only chance to make this work with older kernels would be to disable `tls` (thread-local storage) but which is not possible with glibc 2.14, despite the fact it is offered as a `configure` option.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you can't compile it on the original system likely has nothing to do with kernel version (it could, but 2.2 isn't generally old enough for that to be a stumbling block for most code).  The problem is that the *toolchain* is ancient (at the very least, the compiler).  However, nothing stops you from building a newer version of G++ with the `egcs` that is installed.  You may also encounter problems with `glibc` once you've done that, but you should at least get that far.

What you should do will look something like this:

- Build latest GCC with `egcs`
- Rebuild latest GCC with the `gcc` you just built
- Build latest binutils and `ld` with your new compiler

Now you have a well-built modern compiler and (most of a) toolchain with which to build your sample application.  If luck is not on your side you may also need to build a newer version of `glibc`, but *this* is your problem - the toolchain - not the kernel.