# seg fault when code compiled on machine [x] is run on machine [y] - but why?

Tags: linux, gcc

I've got a dead simple hello world:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("hey I work and stuff!");
  return (0);
}
```

that I've been attempting to compile and port from a VM running `Linux 5.8.0 x86_64 GNU/Linux` to a machine running `Linux 2.6.9-89.EL i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux` with no success. The target is 32-bit, so I've got the `-m32` flag set, as well as the `-static` flag to bake in as much as possible into the executable. I'm in the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc.pdf) and the various `-march` options (i686, i386) don't seem to help. What am I missing here?

*EDIT* found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961622/how-to-port-c-c-applications-to-legacy-linux-kernel-versions) that seems to speak to the issue. I checked and indeed the minimum kernel version shown when I run `file` is above the kernel version on the target:

```
$ file ./test 
./test: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=2d1db51d5ba184e935300681be964298a37ddb4a, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

it seems I need to recompile glibc. if I can make it work I'll post method and results.

Comment: What does `ldd` say for your executable, which libraries could not be statically linked?

Comment: it just says 'not a dynamic executable'

Comment: Not what I expected, maybe [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110192) is helpful.